# Return pointer to a vector from a Class C++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I'm working with Graphs, and I have a Graph Class with a vector of Vertexs, I need to return a pointer to that vector to work with it, but I'm doing some mistake and doesnt Work.

```
class Graph{
public:
    void AddVertex(int vertex){
        Vertex newVertex(vertex);
        vertexs.push_back(newVertex);
        printf(" - Vertex %i added to vertexs\n", newVertex.getNum());
    }

    void CreateEdge(int startVtx, int destVtx, int dist){
        vertexs[(startVtx-1)].AddEdge(&vertexs[(destVtx-1)],dist);
        //vertexs[(destVtx-1)].AddEdge(&vertexs[(startVtx-1)],dist); //SI VOLEM QUE LES ARESTES SIGUIN BIDIRECCIONALS
    }

    Vertex* getVertex(int num){ return &vertexs[(num-1)]; }

    Vertex* begin(){ return &vertexs[0];}

    Vertex* end(){ return &vertexs[(vertexs.size())];}

    vector<Vertex*> getVertexs(){ return &vertexs[0];}

    vector<Vertex>::iterator getItVertexs(){
        std::vector<Vertex>::iterator it = vertexs.begin();
        return it;
    }

    int NumVertexs(){ return vertexs.size(); }

private:
    vector<Vertex> vertexs;     
};

int bfs(Graph* graph){
    int distance[graph->NumVertexs()];
    int level = 1;

    vector<Vertex*> fathers = graph->getVertexs();

    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    Graph graph;
    bfs(&graph);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, in the class I have a method which returns a vector of pointers, and when I call it, I asume that I'm recieving a vector of pointers, but when compiling I have errors ( cant convert type....etc)

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: "What I'm doing wrong?"... using pointers!

Comment: returning `vector<Vertex*>` from a `vector<Vertex> vertexs`? No.

Comment: Hint: plural of "vertex" is *vertices*.

Comment: Learn to read compiler error messages thoroughly, and really try to understand what they're telling you in which actual context!

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40164/should-we-close-fix-my-program-questions

Comment: Massa, why do you say using pointers is wrong? It's more memory efficient than not using them no? By the other side, they're more complex, but i think its worth of it!

Comment: sashoalm, my code its lot more than i just posted, I'm not triying you to do my program, just helping me with a especific problem...

Comment: @rul3s _'It's more memory efficient than not using them no?'_ You heard of using references in c++, didn't you?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ not, I didn't, just searched about it now, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to return a pointer to the underlying array, then use (using your own spelling)

```
Vertex* getVertexs()
{
    return vertexs.data();
}
```

Note that the C++ standard guarantees the data in a vector to be contiguous so this code is safe.

Note that the returned pointer could be invalidated if the vector is modified in any way.

Comment: 'till the next vertex addition in the vector.

Comment: @Johan: very true. I've amended. the answer.